# How to add new lines to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I want to add new lines to each Header but when I do so the first line I add adds to to first line where the preset headers are then continues normally.

What is happening:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Item1,Item2,Item3
Item1,Item2,Item3
Item1,Item2,Item3
```

What I want:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
Item1,Item2,Item3
Item1,Item2,Item3
```

My code:

```py
with open("entries.csv", "a", newline="") as entries:
    fieldnames = [
        "Username",
        "Password",
        "Email",
        "Address 1",
        "Address 2",
        "City",
        "ZIP",
        "State",
        "Country",
        "ETH Address",
        "ETH Private Key",
        "Login Token"
        ]
    data = {
        'Username': reg.username, 
        'Password': reg.password, 
        'Email': reg.email, 
        'Address 1': reg.ShipAddress, 
        'Address 2': reg.ShipAddressCompliment, 
        'City': reg.ShipCity, 
        'ZIP': reg.ShipZip, 
        'State': reg.ShipState, 
        'Country': reg.ShipCountry, 
        'ETH Address': reg.addy, 
        'ETH Private Key': reg.privkey, 
        'Login Token': reg.token
        }
    writer = csv.DictWriter(entries, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Does `"entries.csv"` already contain the header line when you open it? "where the preset headers are" implies yes, so I would make sure the file contains your headers plus a newline. Note that you can start with an empty file and do `writer.writeheader()`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using an existing file with a header row and data rows.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes it does by new line you mean `Header1,Header2,Header3\n` ?

Comment: ******Yes******